# Pass by l-value reference vs pass by value in constructor

Tags: c++, reference

So I have a constructor that takes a `vector<num>&` and them `std::move`'s this reference. Isn't this objectively better than taking `vector<num>` if my intention is to move the argument?

In the second case, as I see it, it's guaranteed that no copies will be inadvertently created when they pass the vec to the constructor.

For the first case, maybe the compiler might optimize out the copy with a move, maybe not, or maybe the user will explcitly do `foo(std::move(my_vec));`, maybe not...in sum, there's no guarantee that it will be moved.

I understand that if I do use a `l-value` reference, I wouldn't be able to accept temporaries. Is there any other drawback(s) to it?

Answer (score 2):

You should always prefer pass-by-reference (passing `std::vector<int>&` or `std::vector<int> const&`) over pass-by-value (passing just `std::vector<int>`) because when passing by reference you are avoiding unnecessary copies.

However, you should not use `std::move` on an l-value reference. `std::move` is used with move-constructors which receive r-value reference like:

```
Foo(std::vector<int>&& v)
    : v_(std::move(v))
{}
```

Comment: why is that `std::move` in there? It seems pointless because `v` is already a temporary

Comment: @nz_21 A named object is *never* a temporary. Thus `v` isn’t either. And no, you should in general not use `std::move` on an lvalue reference since it steals ownership (there are rare cases where it’s OK but these need to be handled with care). You *can*, however, use it on lvalues (i.e. if you passed the vector by value).

Comment: @KonradRudolph thanks for explaining this. I was a bit busy...

Comment: @KonradRudolph Apologies for the incorrect semantics, I meant a reference binding to a temporary, not the temporary itself. I don't get why you need to move a reference binding to a temporary.

Comment: @nz_21 That’s just how the language is defined. If you have `T&& x = some_value; T y = x;`, then `some_value` gets *copied* into `y`. You need to use `std::move(x)` to move the value instead. See https://godbolt.org/z/vfOVPA

Comment: @KonradRudolph but this is an initialization, not an assignment.  Wouldn't the move constructor be called?

Comment: @nz_21 *Both* situations are initialisation. Where do you think assignment is happening?